# Get next sequential Number/Variable Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel

Is there anyway to get the next sequential number or variable in excel if data is already entered in a certain column of excel. I have tried a couple things, but know I am taking a wrong approach. If anyone knows how to do this I would greatly appreciate it.

MLB028Z-MTRSPR-B-A

MLB028Z-MTRSPR-B-B

MLB028Z-MTRSPR-B-C

MLB028Z-MTRSPR-B-D

So on and So on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Excel OLE automation to fire up an instance of Excel and use that to populate the next value and then read that out.

That said OLE automation is like any good movie, there is many a trap lying in wait for the hero in the story, and I would only ever do this if you had no other choice.

Thankfully you do: [Solver Foundation](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/solverfoundation) or [Baynes Algorithms](http://www.google.co.za/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=C#%20baynes%20algorithms&btnK=Google%20Search) (+ loops)

Comment: Thanks for the options I am going to look into one of the others  OLE automation was a route I was going to take but there are definately some problems to overcome.